# Updating database script can't process quotations ( 'x' )

Tags: python, sql-update, firebird

I have been struggling to update a record. I need to update a record with the following query:

```sql
    UPDATE TRIPSHEETDETAILS
    SET MAIL_OFD = 1
    WHERE DELNO = '0000204258'
```

Where I am struggling is that DELNO needs to be in between quotations. ( 'x' )
One of two things will happen it will stop halfway and not complete the run or it will run and not update.

I have tried the following:

```py
mycur.execute("UPDATE TRIPSHEETDETAILS 
                  "set MAIL_OFD = 1 "
                  "where DELNO = '" + array[x][1] + "'" ) 
                                     >array[x][1] will be the value 0000204258 that is in string
```

```py
sql = "UPDATE TRIPSHEETDETAILS SET MAIL_OFD = 1 WHERE DELNO = '%s'"
val = ("0000204258")
mycur.execute(sql, val)
```

```py
a = '0000204258'
mycur.execute(
    "UPDATE TRIPSHEETDETAILS "
    "SET MAIL_OFD = 1 "
    "  where DELNO = '" + a + "'"
    )
```

When doing the folloing it works; which shows me the concept of it works.

```py
mycur.execute(
    """UPDATE TRIPSHEETDETAILS SET MAIL_OFD = 1 WHERE DELNO = '0000204258'"""
    )
```

Something to note. If I change the DELNO to something else that does not require the quotations ('') then it works. However I would prefer to use DELNO.

Comment: In your second example, you shouldn't surround `%s` with quotes. The DB driver should generate the appropriate parameter placeholder, but if you surround it with  quotes, it will simply try to use the **literal** value `%s`.

Comment: Also, depending on the driver you're using, you may need to use `?` instead of `%s`.

Comment: Could you specify which driver you're using (there are at least 4 for Firebird)

Comment: To add all the information about my program. I am using Pycharm with I beleive python 3. The driver I am using is firebirdsql.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel When using ```?``` I can see now that the following is being processed: ```UPDATE TRIPSHEETDETAILS SET MAIL_OFD = 1 WHERE DELNO = ? '0000204258```
Same with ```%s``` which turns into ```UPDATE TRIPSHEETDETAILS SET MAIL_OFD = 1 WHERE DELNO = %s '0000204258'```. However I am starting to see SQL error code -104  Token unknown % and SQL error code -804  SQLDA error

Comment: I am doing this by doing the following. ( not sure if it is correct) 
```sql = """UPDATE TRIPSHEETDETAILS SET MAIL_OFD = 1 WHERE DELNO = ?"""
val = ("'0000204258'")
print(sql,val)
mycur.execute(sql, val)```

Comment: The `?` works then, right? Then I guess pyfirebirdsql (aka firebirdsql) uses only `?` as the parameter placeholder.